# Getting old data back after executing PCA using SPARK

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, pca

I'm using `PCA` to reduce a matrix `m*n` to a matrix `m*2`.

i'm using the snippet inside  [apache spark site](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html) into my project, and it works.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

val mat: RowMatrix = ...

    // Compute the top 2 principal components.
    val pc: Matrix = mat.computePrincipalComponents(2) // Principal components are stored in a local dense matrix.

    // Project the rows to the linear space spanned by the top 2 principal components.
    val projected: RowMatrix = mat.multiply(pc)
```

I haven't seen yet inside the `API` if there is a way to get old data. ***In order to understand what columns `PCA` selected as principal components.***

Is there any library function which does this?

**UPDATE**

***if the PCA algorithm selected and transformed two columns of my data, i want to know how i can verify in which columns of the old data this transformation refers to?***

***EXAMPLE***

multiDimensional Matrix:

```
0 0 0 2 4 
2 4 9 1 3 
3 9 3 2 7 
9 6 0 7 7
```

after PCA algorithm with a reduction on 2 dimensions i will obtain this:

```
-1.4 3  
2 -4.0 
3 -2.9  
-0.9 6
```

Said that, How i can understand which columns PCA selected  **`,as principal components,`**  from original data for reduction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix `pc` contains the principal components as its columns. According to the docs:

> Rows correspond to observations and columns correspond to variables. The principal components are stored a local matrix of size n-by-k. Each column corresponds for one principal component, and the columns are in descending order of component variance.

Thus, you can take a look a the *i*-th column by executing

```scala
val pc: Matrix = ...
val i: Int = ...

for(row <- 0 until pc.numRows) {
  println(pc(row, i))
}
```

**Update**

If you have the input matrix `mat` =

```
0 0 0 2 4 
2 4 9 1 3 
3 9 3 2 7 
9 6 0 7 7
```

where each row constitutes one example and each column a variable, then you can compute the PCA. The two principal components with the most variance are `pc` =

```
0.6072    0.2049
0.3466    0.6626
-0.4674    0.7098
0.4343   -0.1024
0.3225    0.0689
```

Each column constitutes the projection direction to obtain a single dimension of the dimensionality reduced data. In order to obtain now the dimensionality reduced data you calculate `mat * pc` which gives you

```
2.1588    0.0706
-0.2041    9.5523
6.6652    8.9843
12.8425    5.5844
```

This is how your data looks like when it's projected in the lower dimensional vector space. Here again each row represents an example and each column a variable.

If I've understood your question right, then you're looking for the columns of matrix `pc` which tells you how much each original dimension contributes to the projected dimensions. The projection is simply the scalar product of the original data with the projection direction (columns of `pc`).

Comment: The matters is not how to retrieve the principal components, but how them are related to the old data. eg. `if PCA selected for me column 5 , i want to retrieve the old data which it refer`, u understand?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem then. What PCA does for you is to calculate a matrix `pc` whose columns contain the projection directions with greatest variance. Your old data is still stored in `mat`. Only by multiplying `mat` with `pc`, and thus projecting your data, you obtain the dimensionality reduced representation of your original data. At what point do you want to retrieve the old data, then?

Comment: That's what the columns of `pc` will tell you. But it's not necessarily the case that either X1 or X2 are selected. It might also be a combination of both of them, hence projection. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @TillRohrmann I think that's what the OP is misunderstanding, my understanding of what he thinks is that PCA simply takes `k` dimensions and presents them

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk, thanks for clarifying :-) If this is the case, then I can recommend the excellent PCA article on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis. This should make things clear.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk no... i know how pca works. i'm updating this answer soon in order to insert what i want to clarify everything.

Comment: @OiRc that sounds great :-)

Comment: @OiRc, I updated my answer to reflect your updates. I hope this clarifies things.